# Mongodb E11000 duplicate key error on array field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a quick question about mongoose schema real quick. Here is the code: https://i.ibb.co/Db8xPMw/5555.png
I tried to create a document without the property "work". It works in the first time, but it didn't start to work on the second time that I do the same thing again.
Do you have any idea?
Basically I create two documents without an "work" property, which causes a duplicate key error. However, I didn't set up unqiue: true though.

**Error :**

```
"errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.user index work_1 dup key: { : null }
```

Comment: As a suggestion, Please do not add pictures of code/errors, added in text format..

Answer (score 0):

From the message it says your collection has an index with name `work_1` probably on field `work`, Since you've created a document without `work` field then basically you cannot create another document without work field what so ever in the same collection, cause two documents with no `work` field or even `work` field with value as `null` or same cannot exist as it violates unique constraint policies (it says `dup key : { : null}`) !! Uniques indexes can be created via mongoose schemas or can also be created by manually running queries on database.

**Ref :** Search for `Unique Index and Missing Field` in [index-unique](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/)

So you need to drop the existing index using [dropIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/#example) & then if needed recreate it using [createIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/index.html). MongoDB would automatically convert a created index to [index-multikey](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/) (multi-key index - indexes on array fields) if at least one existing document has array value for that indexed field by the time you create index or even if an array value gets inserted for that field in future.

Through code -  **Drop index** : `yourSchema.dropIndex({yourFieldName: 1})` && **Create index** : `yourSchema.index({yourFieldName : 1})`

**NOTE :** Just in case if you want to have certain criteria in `unique indexes` like situation from this question where indexed field can be missing in some documents but it shouldn't be considered as duplicate insertion, then you can take use of [partial-indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#index-type-partial) (Search for Partial Index with Unique Constraint) which would only index documents where `work` field exists.

**Ex of partial-indexes :-**

```
db.yourCollectionName.createIndex(
   { work: 1 },
   { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { work: { $exists: true } } }
)
```

**Ref :** [mongoose-Indexes](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204918/discussion-on-answer-by-srinivasy-mongodb-e11000-duplicate-key-error-on-array-fi).